# Constants in Go established during init

Tags: go

In my Go program, there are configuration values that I want to be constant for the duration of program execution, but that I want to be able to change at the deployment site.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to achieve this with the `const` keyword, since (again, as far as I can tell) its value must be a constant specified at *compile time*.  This means that the only way to achieve what I want would be to declare normal variables and initialize them during the package's `init` function.  It's not that that won't work, but rather that there will now be nothing to prevent these pseudo-constant's values from changing.

My two questions are:

1. Am I missing something about how `const` works?
2. Assuming I'm not, what's the preferred way to handle this?  A public function that returns a private variable that I never expose, never changing it?  Just hoping people don't alter the variables, since they're really configuration settings?

Comment: You could create a type that contains private variables (settable from inside that module's init, but not outside). Then add accessor funcs to the type.  It's not quite the same, but it works that way.

Comment: Better yet: create a file "config.go", create the vars you want to expose, but don't export them (all lower case).  Then create public (upper case) `func`s that give access to each item. No type needed, just a module.

Comment: If you make that an answer, @ChristopherPfohl, I'll select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file "config.go" and create the vars you want to expose.

Don't export them (make them all lower case). Instead create public (upper case) `func`s that give access to each item.

```
package config

var x = 10

func X() int {
   return x
}
```

When you want those variables you simply `import ./config` and use them in code as follows:

```
if config.X()
```

Obviously, you can set the variables in the package `init`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is almost the same as the second method of @Christopher, except that it is not a module, it located in the main package.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

type Config struct {
    debug                bool
    key                  string
    proxyNumber          int
}

func (c *Config) Debug() bool {
    return c.debug
}
func (c *Config) Key() string {
    return c.key
}
func (c *Config) ProxyNumber() int {
    return c.proxyNumber
}

const (
    CONFIG_NAME = "config.ini"
)

var config *Config

func init() {
    DefaultConfig()
    if Exists(CONFIG_NAME) {
        //try to save the config file
    }else {
        //try to load from the config file

    }
}

func DefaultConfig() {
    config = &Config{debug:true, key:"abcde",
        proxyNumber:5,
    }
}

//Exist: check the file exist
func Exists(path string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err == nil { return true }
    if os.IsNotExist(err) { return false }
    return false
}
```

you can use [config](https://github.com/robfig/config) to load and save the config file.

Comment: Good call, I saw this idiom somewhere else recently, can't remember where

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question because it delves into what I suspect may be an omission from Go - immutable state.

From the [language reference](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), "constant expressions may contain only constant operands and are evaluated at compile-time."

You cannot make vars constant, which is a shame. Joe's answer proposes encapsulation as a solution, which will work well - but it's verbose, tedious and might introduce errors.

By comparison, many impure functional languages combine mutable variables with single-assignment immutable values. For example, Scala has the keywords 'val' and 'var'; the meaning of Scala's 'var' is quite similar to Go's 'var'. Immutability is a useful tool in the toolbox because referentially-transparent side-effect-free functions can be written, alongside stateful mutable procedural code. Both have their place. Immutability is also an valuable tool for concurrency because there is no worry about possible race conditions if immutable values are shared between goroutines.

So in my opinion, amongst its many strengths, this is one of Go's shortcomings. It would presumably not be hard to support vals as well as vars, the difference being that the compiler checks that each val is assigned exactly once.

Until that feature is added, you have encapsulation as your only option.

Comment: PS note that Go strings are internally immutable. However, a var that holds a string is itself mutable, even if the string it holds is immutable.

Comment: PS there's a discussion on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/golang-nuts/immutable/golang-nuts/BnjG3N77Ico/5_Unx7u2tusJ

Comment: Because Go has pointers, wouldn't checking for single-assignment be impossible?

Comment: No not really. There's a big difference between checking for single assignment (note the clue's in the name) and immutability. Languages like Scala provide both. You can have one without the other, but it seems more useful to provide for both. In the forum discussion I mentioned, an 'immutable struct' was proposed, which would become immutable once it had been fully initialised. This is a good idea. I see single assignment ('val') as a complementary good idea too.

Comment: Emphasises a part of functional programming missing in Go +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var a string

func main() {
    myvar, err := strconv.Atoi(a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(myvar)
}
```

and compile the program with

```
go build -ldflags '-X main.a 10' test.go
```

That way you can define a constant during compile time.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. However, there's nothing preventing 'a' from being changed except its limited scope. So it's not really a constant, more of a configuration parameter.

Comment: Although, since straight Go lacks compile-time parameters, that's still useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard [go flags](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) with [iniflags](https://github.com/vharitonsky/iniflags). Standard go flags allow setting arbitrary config variables at program start via passing command-line flags, while iniflags "magically" add support for reading config variables from ini files.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the variable in a function that returns its value:

```
func genConst(x int) func() int {
    return func() int {
        return x
    }
}

var Constx = genConst(5)
var x1 = Constx()
```

This way the value cannot be changed by accident, even in the file where it's defined